# rotating a list to the right by "k" times

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code that will rotate a list by "k" times. It works until I try to rotate the list more than 6 times, after 6 times it starts to add the number to my output. I can't seem to find out why.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def rotate(list, num):
    output = []
    for value in range(len(list) - num, len(list)):
        output.append(list[value])
        
    for value in range(0, len(list) - num): 
        output.append(list[value])
          
    return output

rotateNum = int(input("please enter the amount of times that you want the list to rotate: "))

print(rotate(list1, rotateNum))
```

Comment: The problem is that 6 is longer than the length of the list.  You need to start your code with `num = num % len(list)` since your following code doesn't work when `num` is bigger than the length of the list.

Comment: You might also want to look at `collections.deque()`, which already does rotations for you, at the cost of slow indexing.

Comment: The solutions given fix the code, but in case it's not clear, your problem comes from the fact that `range(-1, 6)` will give you the same as `(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, hence the errors you see and the use of modulo as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since on this case rotating by `7` have the same effect as rotating by `1` you have to use the modulus operator on the len of the list. You can also simplify the code by using slice notation:

```py
def rotate(l, num):
    num = num % len(l)
    return l[num:] + l[:num]
```

Note: Don't override built-in reserved words

Comment: This rotates the list to the left.

Comment: You can change the modulo calculation to `num = -num % len(l)` to rotate to the right.

Comment: Use moduli of negative numbers at your own peril @AlainT.

Comment: @Reblochon, Why? The spec. is compliant with Knut's definition and not implementation dependent.

Comment: hehe, then one day, you decide to port your code to java, and it bites you in the butt! proceed with caution!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for rotations as it has an appropriate API and internal structure for efficient rotations:

> **`rotate(n=1)`**
> Rotate the `deque` `n` steps to the right. If `n` is negative, rotate to the left.
> When the `deque` is not empty, rotating one step to the right is equivalent to `d.appendleft(d.pop())`, and rotating one step to the left
> is equivalent to `d.append(d.popleft())`.

```
from collections import deque


if __name__ == '__main__':
    seq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

    steps = int(input("please enter the amount of times that you want the list to rotate: "))

    seq.rotate(steps)
    print(seq)
```

Please note that `list` slice notation requires copying the data, which can be quite inefficient for large data structures. If you need to rotate large collections many times, a `deque` is vastly superior to a `list`, with the caveat that no indexed access is needed on the data - *thanks to @AlainT in the comments for this last detail*

Comment: copying the data to a deque is going to perform the same amount of copying (but less efficiently because of the linking overhead).  Could even be more if the output needs to go back to a list

Comment: It depends @AlainT. If you need to rotate large collections many times, a `deque` is vastly superior to a list.

Comment: I was commenting on the "slice notation requires copying" note which, given that the OP's input (and output) is a list would need to occur on every call (cancelling the  benefits of deque).  Changing the data structure to a deque for the rest of the program would only be a viable option if we could ensure that no indexed access is needed on the data (which is beyond the scope of the question).

Comment: I understand @AlainT., I added your remark that enriches my answer; thank you!